# How to define a relationship that touches grandparents in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

In Laravel, I would like to define a grandparent type eloquent relationship so that I can have the grandchild touch the grandparent when it is added or updated (for instance if it brings the grandparent a very nice birthday card). Say I have a hierarchy like Collection > post > comment.

```
--Comment--
    protected $touches = array('post', 'collection');

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
    public function order()
    {
        // not working
        // return $this->post->collection();
        // not working
        // return $this->belongsTo('Post')->belongsTo('Collection');
    }

--Post--
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Collection');
    }
```

I want the update function in the Collection to run when a Comment is added. How can I set that up?

I'm using Laravel 4.1

Answer (score 0):

> I want the update function in the Collection to run when a Comment is
>   added.

I'm a bit confused about the update function but...

You can register an event handler for that, for example, add this in your `Comment` model:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function($comment)
        {
            // $comment is the current Comment instance
        });
    }
}
```

So, whenever any `Comment` will be created the event handler (anonymous function) will run so you may do something in that function. Read more on [Laravel Website](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events).

Comment: Yup I have that for my Collection class. I was planning on using `protected $touches = ...` to automatically update the collection so that the update would run. It doesn't seem to be working though so I may have to do it by hand